# Select XPath to scrape data with srcapy

Tags: html, xml, scrapy, html-parsing

I have looked at some of the XPath threads on here and read 2 XPath guides but I am having trouble writing a working code to scrape a webpage that is full of restaurants, phone numbers, addresses with scrapy.

**A picture of the source code of the site and the highlighted data I want.**

[image: a picture of the source code of the site and the highlighted data I want.]

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//b")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = kosherscrapeitem
        item ["BusinessName"] = titles.select('//td[@class="line-content"]//html/body/table/tbody/tr[()').extract()
```

This is the data from copying the xpath on chrome:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[485]/td[2]/text()
```

Can someone help me with my Xpath expression?

Comment: Which highlighted data do you want? Just “FALAFEL GRILL, meat”? Or also “Agoura Hills, CA 91301” and “(818) 991-8799”? And also “KOSHER CONNECTION”? Or instead you want to get all 'td class="line=content"' elements? But you want to skip some?

Comment: You should expand on what elements you want to skip. Anything with `Super vision:` text?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I would like to get all the td line comment elements. I should be able to figure out a way to scrub the info that I don't need once I can get the output. What I wanted was to get the Business name, Address, phone number on separate items. I can have a supervision item and then scrub it later. The information after that "KOSHER CONNECTION" is the start of another business name.